# Fix Invalid disk for bootable flash drive without admin rights

Tags: windows, windows-7, boot, usb-flash-drive

I'm trying to re-install Windows 7 Home Premium from a flash drive. I have no admin rights. Please don't ask why - it's the main thing in the question. I know about Rufus, but it requires admin rights as well as any other software for creating bootable drive.

I know that it's possible to create bootable flash drive without admin rights if to unpack all the ISO, then unpack `sources/boot.wim`, copy the file `/1/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi` to the folder `efi/boot` and rename the file to `bootx64.efi`. And yes - it was worked at the first time when I did that.

Now I've did everything the same, but when I try to boot from the flash drive, I receive the error of invalid disk. And I can't understand what and where was changed.

How to easy fix the error without admin rights?

ps. I've even buyed a new flash drive to be sure it's not related to the very drive

Comment: AFAIK the only way a bootable USB can be created in Windows without Admin privs is if it already has a GPT partition table since MBR requires `DiskPart` to set the partition as `Active` for booting from it _(this is likely why Rufus requires Admin privs, but the developer would need to be asked - they're on Superuser, but I can't recall their username)_. Even with UEFI firmware, Windows uses MBR as the default partition table _(switching requires `Clean`, then `Convert GPT` in `DiskPart`)_, but if the USB is GPT, provided it has the correct EFI files/hierarchy, it should boot w/ UEFI firmware.

Comment: Is the motherboard UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: If the character limit hasn't been exceeded, please edit a comment, or if the 5min grace period has ended and no one has commented after it, please copy/paste it into a new comment and delete the old. To determine whether the motherboard firmware is BIOS or UEFI, go into the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings and check the Boot page - UEFI will have EFI boot options, Secure Boot, and on non-newer motherboards, an option to enable CSM [Legacy] Mode.

Comment: Where can I see my motherboard is EFI or BIOS? I recalled a detail that may be the point. The previous flash drive I successfully installed Windows from was formatted by Rufus in the past. But later I formatted it by the "Format..." option of the right-click menu. Did I remove MBR/GPT and that caused the issue? Under "the developer" maybe you mean superuser.com/users/286681/akeo ? [Developer of Rufus]

Comment: When I press F2 and go to the Boot tab, I see only the boot priority order and nothing else. If I would copy Win ISO to flash drive again via Rufus and later just delete all the files from the drive, but not format it with the "Format..." option, it will be still bootable, am I right?

Comment: As stated in my first comment, a bootable flash drive on a BIOS motherboard requires the partition be set `Active` in `DiskPart` and that it contain boot files, whereas a GPT formatted flash drive on a UEFI motherboard simply requires the requisite EFI boot files. Due to `DiskPart`, creating a bootable flash drive requires Admin privs - it doesn't matter if it's a Windows InstallUSB or a Linux LiveUSB, it requires `DiskPart`.