# Does right-click Format option remove MBR from USB flash drive?

Tags: windows, boot, usb, mbr, rufus

As I can understand, if we format a USB flash drive by Rufus and copy to the drive Windows ISO files by Rufus, later delete all the ISO files from the drive by Del key, the drive would be still bootable with MBR. Is it correct?

If so, what if we later would format the drive by the "Format" option of the Windows right-click context menu? Does this operation remove MBR from the drive and make it non-bootable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I can understand, if we format a USB flash drive by Rufus and copy to the drive Windows ISO files by Rufus, later delete all the ISO files from the drive by Del key, the drive would be still bootable with MBR. Is it correct?

No.
First, there is just one ISO file system that you copy to a USB flash drive using Rufus. If you later delete files in the partition that won't affect the MBR and the boot sector of the partition so "bootability" will still be there. But without any files in a partition the remaining boot code in the boot sector will fail. It really depends on what you consider "bootable".

> If so, what if we later would format the drive by the "Format" option of the Windows right-click context menu? Does this operation remove MBR from the drive and make it non-bootable?

No, the MBR will not be removed and the format operation does not affect the flag within the MBR that marks a bootable partition.

The MBR will only be affected if your format operation changes the file system. That would require changing the file system type identifier in the MBR.

Comment: If the change of file system just CHANGES MBR, but doesn't remove it and boot sector of the active partition as well as formatting without changing file system, will the "bootablity" still be there too?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the scenario. Could you repeat it in a point by point description what you would like to do? Thank you.

Comment: I would like to have empty USB flash drive, but so that I could at any moment just copy extracted ISO files to such drive without admin privs and Rufus as I described by the link https://superuser.com/q/1728192

Comment: If you restricted yourself to operations within your file system, such as deleting and copying, anything outside won't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get our terms right :

- MBR and GPT are two *partition styles*
- Formatting the partition creates a *file-system* such as NTFS or FAT32.

The two terms are distinct and one has no relation to the other
(beside some inherent limitations).

In addition, deleting all the files in the partition will make the disk
unbootable if the boot uses data that is in the partition.
The small initial bootstrap code that is placed by Rufus inside the first
few sectors of the disk will stay, so the disk may possibly look as
bootable to the BIOS, but the boot will fail in this case.